# React : All the Modal gets opened at once and only last one shows up when I'm passing props inside modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I open Modal all the modal opens at once and only the last one shows up. I have a list of cards that using props to map all the data but when I map data inside the modal only the last one data shows up.

I've tried different modal, but the problem is same. I'm new to React and I've spent 3 Hrs but it's not solved.

```
  const Products = () => {
 const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
 const onOpenModal = () => setOpen(true);
 const onCloseModal = () => setOpen(false);

const products = Data.map(product => {
  <p className='name' onClick={onOpenModal}>{product.title} </p> 
      <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
    <p className = "modal-desc">{product.desc}</p>
 </Modal> }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because all your products rely on the same `useState`. To fix this, you should create an individual `useState` for each modal. This is probably best achieved by wrapping the product in another child class like so:

```
const ProductChild = ({ title, desc }) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const onOpenModal = () => setOpen(true);
    const onCloseModal = () => setOpen(false);

    return (
        <p className='name' onClick={onOpenModal}>{title}</p> 
        <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
            <p className = "modal-desc">{desc}</p>
        </Modal>
    );
}

const Products = () => {
    const products = Data.map(product => (
        <ProductChild desc={product.desc} title={product.title} />
    ));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your modal at the `Products` you can create a new component called `ProductItem` and have your `Modal` inside that component . In this way you will have the modal state tied to that product item alone .

```
const Products = () => {
  return data.map(product => (
   <ProductItem product={product} key={product.id} />
 )
}


const ProductItem = ({ product}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const onOpenModal = () => setOpen(true);
  const onCloseModal = () => setOpen(false);
 
  return (
    <>
    <p className='name' onClick={onOpenModal}>{product.title} </p> 
    <Modal open={open} onClose={onCloseModal} center>
  <p className = "modal-desc">{product.desc}</p>
</Modal>
</>
  )
}
```